# How do I evaluate this without using taylor expansion :$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2\log(\frac {x+1}{x})-x\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, taylor-expansion

> How do I evaluate this without using Taylor expansion?
>
> $$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2\log\left(\frac {x+1}{x}\right)-x$$

**Note**: I used Taylor expansion at $z=0$ and I have got $\frac{-1}{2}$

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

**An approach** is to set $u:=\dfrac1x$, then you are looking for
$$
\lim_{u \to 0}\left(\frac{\log (1+u)-u}{u^2}\right)
$$ then you may conclude with L'Hospital's rule
$$
\lim_{u \to 0}\left(\frac{\log (1+u)-u}{u^2}\right)=\lim_{u \to 0}\left(\frac{\frac1{1+u}-1}{2u}\right)=\lim_{u \to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{-1}{(1+u)^2}}{2}\right)=-\frac12.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this however i used it

Comment: After the first Hopital you are left with $\frac{1-(1+u)}{2u(1+u)}=-\frac1{2(1+u)}$, so that the result can be obtained without the second invocation of el Hop.

Comment: @LutzL You are right! Usually, I don't use L'Hospital's rule: I find the Taylor expansion really efficient. Thank you for your remark!

Comment: Additionally, there is not much difference between using l'Hopital and the Taylor expansion. They are very closely related as immidiate consequences of the mean value theorem, the Taylor expansion is only a little more work in the coefficients, but more powerful in the application.

Comment: @LutzL Right. That's why I've started my answer with "an approach is...", I had not seen the OP special intention:)

Comment: This was no critique, just my extra 2 cent. The question explicitly excludes Taylor expansions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [following (very convenient) inequality](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf):
$$
\frac{2x}{2+x} \leq \ln(1+x) \leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}
$$
which holds for $x \geq 0$. In your case, you have $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$, leading to
$$
x^2\frac{\frac{2}{x}}{2+\frac{1}{x}} -x \leq x^2\ln\!\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) -x \leq x^2\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}} - x.
$$

- For the LHS:
  $$
  x^2\frac{\frac{2}{x}}{2+\frac{1}{x}} -x = x\left(\frac{2}{2+\frac{1}{x}} - 1\right) = x\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{x}}{2+\frac{1}{x}}\right) = \frac{-1}{2+\frac{1}{x}} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} -\frac{1}{2}.
  $$
- And the RHS:
  $$\begin{align}
  x^2\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}} - x
  &= x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}} - 1\right)
  = x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}\right)\\
  &= x\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)}\right)\\
  &= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)}
   \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} -\frac{1}{2}.
  \end{align}$$
  It only remains to invoke the squeeze theorem.

(I also strongly suggest bookmarking the "useful inequalities sheet" linked at the beginning.)

Comment: The point here is not to argue this is the most efficient approach (see @Olivier Oloa's answer with L'Hopital, or the -- not allowed here -- Taylor expansion approach) -- mostly that very often, there is a good known inequality somewhere that will do the trick. And gives slightly more than just the limit as well , since you get quantifiable bounds in terms of simpler functions. (Also that there are other ways than L'Hopital.)